# rythm engine in parallel processing Issue

Tags: rythm

As per javadoc, RythmEngine class is not thread safe I.e. each time I have to build a new class which looks like an overhead. What is the best way to use rythm engine in multi threaded envioronment.

Below sample code is for illustration.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
import org.rythmengine.RythmEngine;

public class RythmEngineUtil {
    static RythmEngine engine;
    static {
        Map<String, Object> conf;// = configure the object
        engine = new RythmEngine(conf);
    }

    public static String render(File file, Map<String,Object> param){
        return engine.render(file, param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you construct and init the engine when you app bootstrap, then that instance should be safely used in a multi-threaded environment

Comment: So, exact same instance can be invoked from multiple threads at the same time? Does all request gets synchronized in engine or they run parallel without any issue?  Sorry to ask these question as I am getting confused with javadoc which says that this class is not thread safe.

Comment: The engine takes time to compile templates and build them into bytecode, during that process, it is not thread safe. But once it is loaded the template itself (literally a Java class) is stateless and can be used in multiple threads environment